# AngularJS SPA Login Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, single-page-application

I have an Angularjs single page application and now I would like to add a login page to it. Here is my SPA template `plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/WgUDJQNL0YCKWUfXMFsr?p=preview. I need a login page and not a modal(examples are available for login page as modal). User has to view the information page(which is in above plunker) only after logging in. Have gone through various videos and tutorials on this but couldn't find a solution. As am new to angularjs, would be grateful if anyone can provide the code for this.

Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the body content from index and put it in a separate file(home.html). Just add a ui-view in the body. In run block route to login page by default. On login success route to your home page using `$state.go('home')`. Name the tab routes as home.tab1 and home.tab2 for Nested routes.

Comment: how to set a successful login? Could you provide the code pls

Comment: Well, i can't give you a login page code... It depends on your application and the security level you need. There are lots of free login templates out there. You can use them if you don't want to write it yourself.If you can update the plunker with a login page i can fix the routes.

Comment: Here I have a basic template in `plunker`:http://plnkr.co/edit/JETxXfQwkvN0Ibk4m46J?p=preview. The issue is when I login, the tabs(tab1 in example) are not clickable. Please help to sort this out.

Comment: Could you please check it now..(enter any id and paswd, click on sign in to see the logo and tabs)

Comment: Remove the script and link tag from dashboard. it's already in index.html. There is something wrong with your bootstrap code. i copy pasted your code from the question into this then it working. http://plnkr.co/edit/7jlJiuZFFt0xeKzlc8lv?p=preview

Comment: Thanx a lot for the support..But here http://plnkr.co/edit/YYcV5DG2EKKalcJzpLUg?p=preview, when I click on tab1 the content is being displayed on navbar instead in the body. Tried including ui-view in body but still it doesn't work!!

Comment: What you are trying to do is called Nested Views. You have to add a view in dashboard.html and change the route name to **parentName.childName**. Then if you call that it'll work. Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/3uW04rWjDgsax9ps40hs?p=preview

Comment: Thanx a lot for the solution and your explanation too.. Could you let me know how to authenticate the login page..

Comment: What do you mean? How to check whether username and password is correct? or How to authorize whether the user can view a page or not?

Comment: Actually I am new to angularjs, it would be very useful for me if you could help me in knowing both please..

Comment: To check username and password write logic to compare credentials with your db and to authorize the user to view the page you have to use Resolve option in the Route provider.

Comment: If my answer is useful please accept it as the answer for this question.

Comment: Definitely it is.. sorry for the delay!!